# InvalidIndexError when using map() on a dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm getting the error `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` when I attempt to concatenate two dataframes. I believe the issue is present somewhere in this code where I map a column to another column.

```
mapping_g = {'Hospice' : ['ALLCARE', 'CARING EDGE MINOT', 'CARING EDGE HERMANTOWN', 'CARING EDGE BISMARK', 'BLUEBIRD HOSPICE', 'DOCTORS HOSPICE', \
    'FIRST CHOICE HOSPICE', 'KEYSTONE HOSPICE' , 'JOURNEY\'S HOSPICE', 'LIGHTHOUSE HOSPICE', 'SALMON VALLEY HOSPICE'] ,'Group': ['ACH1507', \
    'CE11507', 'CE21507', 'CE51507', 'BBH1507', 'DOC1507', 'FCH1507', 'KEY1507', 'JOU1507', 'LHH1507', 'SVH1507']}

g_mapping_df = pd.DataFrame(data=mapping_g)
g = dict(zip(g_mapping_df.Group, g_mapping_df.Hospice))
raw_pbm_data['Name Of Hospice'] = raw_pbm_data['GroupID'].map(g)

combined_data = pd.concat([raw_direct_data,raw_pbm_data], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

I think it's something to do with when I place the GroupID column into the Name of Hospice column in the second to last line.

Comment: Please post a sample of `raw_pbm_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Realized that `raw_pbm_data['Name Of Hospice'] = raw_pbm_data['GroupID'].map(g)`
should have actually been `raw_pbm_data['HospiceName'] = raw_pbm_data['GroupID'].map(g)`

I'm working with a bunch of different Excel files and all the column names are slightly different while all being similar. I can't manually rename the Excel files because they're in the format my employer wants them to be in, so I am juggling the information in dataframes. Therefore, the above change solved my issue as it was simply appending a new column onto the dataframe instead of replacing an existing column, which I believe makes sense as to why concatenate was breaking.